# Read double from keyboard in Java

Tags: java

How can I read a double variable from keyboard in Java? I'm trying to solve this, but it didn't works. It said:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864) at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485) at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413) at Main.main(Main.java:7)

### My code

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
        String s = scanner.next();
        double d = scanner.nextDouble();
        int myI = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + myI);

    }
}
```

Comment: What input did you type?

Comment: You've probably messed up while giving the inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use BufferedReader Class to take Double as input.
It can be taken as

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String s=br.readLine();

Double d=Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());

int i=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Answer (score 4):

Tried to reproduce, had no luck. I think that the problem is with your input.
here is what I have tried:

input:

```
s

4.51

2
```

output:

```
String: s
Double: 4.51
Int: 2
```

In your code your first scaner takes `string`, second: `double` and third takes `int`.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class DoubleDouble
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      double value;
      Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );

      System.out.print("Enter a double:");
      value = scan.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("value: " + value +" twice value: " + 2.0*value );
    }
}
```

And be sure, that you type: For example:  3.14 
so the dot, should be a point

Comment: I think too, that there's an issue with the code...
I know that his code is okey, and that there is not an issue with the code, but It does not hurt this code, and be sure that the input is right

Answer (score 0):

the code you have written is totally correct ,you should check your input order
string
double
int

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because of input order. Make sure you are inputing a string, double then integer. In that specific order.